# PHP Pass Variable To Include File

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass variable to my config file which connects to my DB, the echo outputs the username fine from my config file (File 2).

File 1:

```
<?php

$gUsername = $_GET['pUsername'];
include 'configs/config.php';
global $gUsername;
....
```

File 2:

```
<?php

echo $gUsername;

$servername = "myserver";
$username = "user_$gUsername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "db_$gUsername";

?>
```

When I echo username and database name I get what I want:

```
$username = user_john
$dbname = db_john
```

However the DB connect does not recognize these variables:

```
user_ db_ Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user_'@'my_ip' (using password: YES)
```

Edited: The DB Query as requested:

```
$gUsername = $_GET['pUsername'];
include 'configs/config.php';
global $gUsername;


//echo $gUsername;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: show how/where you're doing the db stuff...

Comment: And one hint: you do not want to use `global`. You just don't. Seriously.

Comment: if your "file 2" is configs/config.php, this code will echo your GET variable. (and no you don't want to use `global`, it is pure evil)

Comment: funny enough when I add an extra underscore on the username I get user__john db_john Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user__john'@'my_ip' (using password: YES)

Comment: remove `global $gUsername;`

Comment: @Pedro I just did, same issue, the variables are not recognized, perhaps has something to do with the underscore

Comment: @user5174952, did you try `$servername = "myserver";
$username = "user_" . $gUsername;
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "db_" . $gUsername;` ?